# change UICollectionViewCell height with animation

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uianimation

I want to change size of `CollectionViewCell` when cell is clicked. Cell needs to expand or collapse if it is opened already. I am doing it so far with this code inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method:

```
UICollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[UIView transitionWithView:collectionView duration:.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
     animations:^{
        CGRect oldFrame = myCell.frame;
        if ([expandedCell isEqual:myCell]) {
            expandedCell = nil;
            oldFrame.size.height = 42;
        }else{
            expandedCell = myCell;
            oldFrame.size.height = 220;
        }
            myCell.frame = oldFrame;

   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

When I expand last cell it works fine. It collapses fine too. But when I click on cell at index 0 for example, frame of cell 0 is going under frame of cell 1. How can I change frames of all cells after selected index path? Don't forget, I need animation while changing all cell frames.

EDIT: I found answer on my question with next few lines of code. Point is that you need to call reload data inside animation so that changing size inside `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` will be animated.

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to resize the height in collection view height delegate and reload that particular cell in `didSelectItem`